# How to catch error from within async block (in F#)?

Tags: exception, f#, try-catch

For reasons unknown, I can't figure out anything that will return the error without crashing the code!

In F#,

// This function may throw an error (e.g., the filepath may not exist). Enclose it in an outer Async block to catch errors.

```
let writeJsonAsync (r:Report[]) (file:string) = 
      async {
             
                let json = Json.serialize r

                let directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file) // file is the absolute path.

                if  Directory.Exists directory
                then 
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, json)  // creates a new file if the file is not created. It will overwrite the existing file.
                else 
                    raise <| DirectoryNotFoundException()  <***--NO MATTER WHAT, THIS CRASHES!
           }


// Save to local file with Json.
let saveReportConfigurationAsync (r:Report[], file:string)  = 
    async {
       let! foo = 
          async  {
                   try 
                        return! writeJsonAsync r file
                   with ex -> failwith "unreachable"                     
                 }
        
       foo  
    }
```

Any help is most appreciated. TIA

Comment: Does changing `return! writeJsonAsync r file` to `let! res =  writeJsonAsync r file` and then `return res` fix it?

Comment: @CoopC  Nope. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Async.Catch`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#Catch) should do what you want. If the async computation completes successfully, it will return `Choice1Of2` with the returned value. If the computation raises an exception before it completes, then it will return `Choice2Of2` with the raised exception:

```ml
let saveReportConfigurationAsync (r:Report[], file:string)  = 
    async {
        match! Async.Catch(writeJsonAsync r file) with
            | Choice1Of2 () -> printfn "Success"
            | Choice2Of2 exn -> printfn $"{exn.Message}"
    }
```

Comment: Still crashes on raise <| DirectoryNotFoundException(). ??? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the debugger, and this code will run correctly as expected!  Thanks.  (See below).

Answer (score 0):

@BrianBerns is correct. Ultimately, the problem was not in the code, but rather in running it with the visual studio debugger! The debugger catches the error before it can be escalated to the calling Async.Catch() method.

Below is the working code (which runs perfectly!).

```
// This function may throw an error (e.g., the filepath may not exist). Enclose it in an outer Async block to catch errors.
    // Note: The errors are caught correctly when NOT in debugging mode,i.e., "Start Without Debugging". The Debugger will catch the error before it is
    //       escalated to the calling Async.Catch().
    let writeJsonAsync (r:Report[]) (file:string) :Async<string> = 
          async {
                    let write (json:string)  = System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, json)  // creates a new file if the file is not created. It will overwrite the existing file.
 
                    let directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file) // file is the absolute path.
                    match Directory.Exists directory with
                    | false -> raise <| DirectoryNotFoundException(); return "Failed"
                             
                    | _     -> 
                               let cmpCfg : ComputerConfiguration = 
                                   // returns the computer name set during installation. NetBIOS and hostname are initially set to the same name.
                                   let computername = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME")           
                                   {ComputerName = computername; Reports = Some r}

                               let deserialized : StargateConfiguration = File.ReadAllText(file) |> Json.deserialize<StargateConfiguration> 
                               let hasCmpCfg = deserialized.StargateConfiguration |> Array.tryFind (fun t -> t.ComputerName = cmpCfg.ComputerName)

                               let newStargateConf (s:ComputerConfiguration[]) : ComputerConfiguration[] = s |> Array.append [|cmpCfg|]
                               match hasCmpCfg with
                               |None ->  let y = newStargateConf deserialized.StargateConfiguration 
                                         {StargateConfiguration = y} |> Json.serialize |> write
                                         return "Success!"
                                         
                               |Some _ -> let y = deserialized.StargateConfiguration 
                                                  |> Array.map (fun t -> if t.ComputerName = cmpCfg.ComputerName then cmpCfg else t) 
                                          {StargateConfiguration = y} |> Json.serialize |> write 
                                          return "Success!"                                    
               } 

    // Save to local file with Json. 
    let saveReportConfigurationAsync (r:Report[], file:string) : Async<string>  = 
        async {
             match! Async.Catch(writeJsonAsync r file) with
                | Choice1Of2 msg -> return msg
                | Choice2Of2 error -> return $"Error! {error.Message}"                      
        }
```